# How can I create an RSA instance with RSAPSS algorithm in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, rsa

```
var rsa = RSA.Create("RSAPSS");
```

I am using this code to create an RSA instance. It works in .NET Framework 4.7.2 but it returns null in .NET Core and in .NET 5 on a Windows OS.

`RSA.Create("RSA")` works both in .NET Framework and core. Is there a way to make `RSAPSS` work in .NET Core or is it not supported ?

I have checked [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography), it says PSS padding is supported for windows and linux. RSACng is supported for Windows but not for Linux. But I am confused as to why I am getting null if it is supported in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that the same code was working fine in .NET Framework but not in .NET Core, my project was targeting .NET standard.

In my use-case I create `RSA` instance with `RSA.Create("RSAPSS")` and then import `RsaParameters` with [ImportParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.importparameters?view=net-5.0) method. If I do not use `RSAPSS` as the algorithm name and create the default RSA implementation, it throws an error when signing hash with `Pss` padding saying the padding mode is not supported.

I have found out that the `RSA.Create` method has [an overload that takes `RsaParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.create?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_RSA_Create_System_Security_Cryptography_RSAParameters_) in .NET Core. I have tested this overload and see that it works with `Pss` padding. So I have just added a check for the runtime, if it's .NET Core I use this overload, if not, I use the same code as before and it solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use overloaded methods which accepts `RSASignaturePadding` parameter:

```
var rsa = RSA.Create(2048);
var sign = rsa.SignHash(new byte[32], HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
bool ok = rsa.VerifyHash(new byte[32], sign, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
```

Comment: Unfotunutely that doesn't work, it throws and error saying the padding mode is not supported.

Comment: @SelmanGenç what system are you using? it works for me, .net core 3.1, windows 10

Comment: my code is a bit different, after I create the RSA, I parse a PEM file for a private key and import the RSA parameters from there.